# What is the best way to hard code a DataFrame that I get as a console output?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a code-snippet that I am running on the PyCharm Python Console and in return getting a DataFrame, let's say size (20, 2).

Is there a way in PyCharm or in the Python Console to get a definition-style copy of this DataFrame so that I can directly paste it in my .py file to hard code it?

Comment: Maybe you want `df.to_dict()`?

Comment: Ah, yeah, then I can do `DataFrame.from_dict()`